# Side Navigation Click Not Working

Tags: ios, github, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I have implemented this slide menu from library [iOS Slide Menu](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu) and used the uitabbarcontroller.

Home viewcontroller is having this slidemenu but on click of side navigation bar slide bar menu is appear but on click of records any action not happen. Whereas if I use the this slidemenu without tabbarcontroller than it is working.

Anyone if implemented this slide menu under the uitabbarcontroller using the storyboard using objective C in IOS. Please share your answer.

Comment: can you please share your code...

Comment: Okay, https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofrev4hhiyexr65/iOS-Slide-Menu.zip?dl=0

Comment: Are you want `UITabBar` After Login?

Comment: Yes, but not after login.  I need to use tabbar first section for home where these side navigation bar should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code some of the changes I made like `self.window.rootViewController` into `App Delegate`.

Also I changed into the `SlideNavigationController` define new `UINavigationController` then give the `Storyboard Id` that access into the code which is below.

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"
                                                             bundle: nil];
 self.landingScreen = (SlideNavigationController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"launchingNVCtr"];
```

Also some code changes into the `appDelegate`.

```
-(void)setupDrawers{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"
                                                             bundle: nil];
    self.landingScreen = (SlideNavigationController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"launchingNVCtr"];

    LeftMenuViewController *leftMenu = (LeftMenuViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                                 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"LeftMenuViewController"];

    RightMenuViewController *rightMenu = (RightMenuViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"RightMenuViewController"];

    self.landingScreen = [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance];
    self.landingScreen.rightMenu = rightMenu;
    self.landingScreen.leftMenu = leftMenu;
    self.landingScreen.menuRevealAnimationDuration = 0.18f;
    // Creating a custom bar button for right menu
    UIButton *button  = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gear"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] action:@selector(toggleRightMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.landingScreen.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidClose object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
        NSLog(@"Closed %@", menu);
    }];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidOpen object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
        NSLog(@"Opened %@", menu);
    }];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidReveal object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
        NSLog(@"Revealed %@", menu);
    }];
}
```

Then following method for calling when tap on `Log In` button.

```
-(void)displayLandingScreen{
    [self setupDrawers];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.landingScreen;
}
```

Following code for when user tap on `Log out`.

```
-(void)logOutPressed{
    //mainTabBar
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"
                                                             bundle: nil];
    UITabBarController *loginTab = (UITabBarController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"mainTabBar"];

    self.window.rootViewController = loginTab;
}
```

[Also same code retrieve from the HERE.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sv6qf8v267c39ya/iOS-Slide-Menu-master.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Not still having some issue. I don't need those login view controller, Required direct Home Page on First tabbar section which I did in this new version. Now the side navigation click is not workable the issue. https://www.dropbox.com/s/34qzh8pyg78hyok/iOS-Slide.zip?dl=0

Comment: @CJIOSDeveloper Man, that's your project flow but I created as per you want.

Comment: But I did the required changes and not working. Can you suggest any alternatives.

Comment: In this case you can see that when click the side bar row only navigation is closed and view controller is not loaded fresh.

Comment: Have you glance the didselect row delegate in left viewcontroller of IOSslide menu app where on click the new controller is not loaded.

Comment: Hi, can you review your last dropbox build where the new view controller is not loaded on click of didselect row delegate of sidenavigation.

Comment: @CJIOSDeveloper what have you try after I gave you example.

Comment: @CJIOSDeveloper can you please give me another source code I haven't code kindly give me I'll try to solve your problem.

Comment: @CJIOSDeveloper I'll try to solve problem once completed I'll inform you.

Comment: @CJIOSDeveloper You can download the source code from here...https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mai7tdo6l7hwrn/iOS-Slide%20-%20Solution.zip?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97397/discussion-between-nimit-parekh-and-cj-ios-developer).